# Adaptec configuration has changed - Why can't it show me what it sees before blindly "accept" or "reject"ing?

Tags: raid, configuration, bios, adaptec

I work with Adaptec cards on a regular basis; 2405, 5405, 6405e, 6805, and a few others.

I am dismayed by the BIOS' terseness and lack of any utility at all.

I can set card setting toggles; but the real issue I want to know:  What does the card see as the array?!

I had a working array.  Its a RAID1.

I then swapped the 2 disk cables, to see what would happen, and now its asking me to blindly accept or reject the configuration changes.

I can't even see what drives it *thinks* are there, without 'accepting' the change.

I don't want to 'accept' ANYTHING blindly.

What is the proper way to assess the current status of "what the RAID card thinks the disks are" ?

I then moved the cables back to the original disks, and allowed the BIOS to load again.  I did not accept anything, and instead allowed it to time-out.

The BIOS now shows a degraded array, with 1 "inaccessible" disk even though both are connected to the card now.

This is beyond broken by design.  What is the "proper" way to assess the status of 2 actual disks as to what the Adaptec RAID card thinks they are, before blindly acecepting or rejecting configurations?

The biggest issue is that "reject" disallows any and all viewing of the arrays, as it comes back "no arrays present".

What can be done to help a fellow not pull his hair out any further :)

Comment: If that is your problem wait until you see the new web based shiny non functional web frontend tht gives zero information about what is going on.

Comment: Newer adaptec controllers have less features in their legacy ROM than in UEFI. Do you have a mainboard capable of UEFI? If so, try to enable it and see if the controller menu appears inside the UEFI setup. It was the only way I could set up hot spares etc..

Answer (score 2):

Greetings from Adaptec by PMC!

All the controllers you mentioned do store the physical device configuration in the NVSRAM on the controller.  The post message should give some indication of the configuration change i.e.:

Drive CN0 port 0 is no longer present

or similar.  If you have knowingly made a change to the physical drives attached it should be safe to accept the change assuming you have not removed more drives than your RAID level can tolerate.  If you have not made any changes to the drives then it's best to check the post message to see if you can determine the fault and reject the changes to review the "last known good" configuration.

If you'd like more information or further explanation, please open a case online at ask.adaptec.com or call to speak with a technician at 408.934.7274

Best Regards,
Adaptec by PMC Technical Support